# Stubbing a private function that returns a promise

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon

I'm completely new to frontend testing and I'm having some trouble progressing with a particular test. I'm using Mocha, Sinon and Chai.

Basically I have some private functions that I would like to test. I don't want to expose them to the API so I'm trying to mock the functions instead using Sinon.

One of the private functions returns a promise and has roughly the following structure:

```
myPrivateFunc(arg1, arg2).done(function(x) {
  if (x.length > 0) {
    // do something
  } else {
    // call some other private function 
  }
});
```

I tried to stub this by doing something like this:

```
sinon.stub(object, 'myPrivateFunction').withArgs(args1, args2);
```

When I call the public function in my test, the private function is correctly called, but of course eventually fails:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined`

I've tried messing around with `.returns()` but I'm not really sure what I'm doing at all.

Could anybody point me in the right direction? I've looked at other similar questions and couldn't really find a suitable answer.

Comment: Your test double needs to return an object which implements a method called `done`.

Comment: NB: `done` is not standard for a promise. You should better use `then`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed use `.returns` to specify the value that the sub should return. That value should have a `done` property.

Possibly you are using a jQuery or similar deferred object (e.g. returned by `$.ajax`) which exposes a `done` method (which is not standard for promises: `then` would be a better option). If that is indeed what you use, you could create a dummy deferred object for the stub's return value:

```
sinon.stub(object, 'myPrivateFunction')
     .withArgs(args1, args2)
     .returns($.Deferred().resolve([1,2,3]));
```

Replace `[1,2,3]` with whatever value you want *x* to be.

Otherwise you can always create a plain object that has the `done` method:

```
sinon.stub(object, 'myPrivateFunction')
     .withArgs(args1, args2)
     .returns( { done: x => [1,2,3] } );
```

Comment: Ah this works! Thank you very much. I'll need to find out why `.done` was used instead of `.then`. Switching to `.then` works just as well. :-S Both of your methods described above solve my issue. Thanks again!